# WPF - MVVM Light - Command - Send Login/Password from View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

Could you tell me how to send 2 values from 2 TextBox in my View with MVVM Light.

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.View.LoginV"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    DataContext="{Binding Login, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <TextBox x:Name="EdtLogin" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="EdtPassword" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="Login"  Command="{Binding SendLoginPasswordCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EdtPassword, Path=Text}"/>
</Grid>
```

Here it s fine to send the value of the EdtPassword TextBox but how can I also send EdtLogin at the same time ? And how do I update my VM to receive them?

Here is my VM:

```
public LoginVM()
    {
        SendLoginPasswordCommand = new RelayCommand(doLogin, canSendLoginPasswordCommand);
    }
    #region SendLoginPasswordCommand
    private bool canSendLoginPasswordCommand()
    {
        return true;
    }
    private void doLogin()
    {
        ViewModelLocator.MainStatic.IsLoginState = false;
        ViewModelLocator.MainStatic.IsNotLoginState = true;
    }
    public RelayCommand SendLoginPasswordCommand { get; private set; }
    #endregion
```

Thx

ANSWER:
Actually I should do this, stupid me:

```
<TextBox x:Name="EdtLogin" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Login}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="EdtPassword" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Password}"/>
    <Button Content="Login" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,3,58,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" Height="21"
            Command="{Binding SendLoginPasswordCommand}"/>
```

Comment: Actually I m just thinking that I was not thinking the right way. I Guess I shoudl have 2 string properties in my VM and bind them to my TextBox...

Comment: I sure hope your Password property isn't a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare 2 properties in your VM and to bind them in OneWayToSource or TwoWay mode to your TextBoxes.

The other solution is to implement a MultiValue binding that would convert 2 strings from your TextBoxes into a structure. But this second method is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I should do this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="EdtLogin" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Login}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="EdtPassword" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Password}"/>
    <Button Content="Login" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,3,58,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" Height="21"
            Command="{Binding SendLoginPasswordCommand}"/>
```